# PHP Websocket on Bluehost

Tags: php, websocket, chat, shared-hosting

I am trying to setup Websocket based PHP chat application from [Chat-Using-WebSocket-and-PHP-Socket](https://github.com/sanwebe/Chat-Using-WebSocket-and-PHP-Socket/) on [Bluehost](https://www.bluehost.com/) on domain XYZ.ABC.com.

I have changed $host to XYZ.ABC.com both in server.php & index.php.

I am not able find a way to invoke & keep server.php alive.

Is any other way to get this done? even switching hosing provider works for me.

Comment: You need a way to get access to the shell.  This means don't use shared hosting.  A quick 10 second glance at Bluehost shows that they have VPS hosting... that might do the trick, but do your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have shell access you need to run the script with

```
nohup <command> &
```

It will then run in background and not stop if you leave the shell.

If you don't have SSH access there is no chance in keeping it alive.
Look for a cheap vserver or rootserver with SSH access then.