# React-Native: How to get socket.io to work on live server

Tags: react-native, express, socket.io

I'm using express with socket.io version 2.2.0 from this url:
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io#readme

Im using socket.io in a react-native app and it works perfectly when running on localhost, but now I'm trying to move to a live server for beta testing, and I'm not sure how to get it to work on the live server. I'm using Bluehost.

Here is now I set it up for running on the localhost:

In any component:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.socket = io('http://IPADDRESS:3000', {
        jsonp: false
    });
    this.socket.on('some_string', () => this.someFunction());
}
```

Setting up socket.io in app.js file:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('some_string', function (some_value) {
        socket.join(some_value);
    });
    ...
});
```

Through my hosting service with Bluehost, I have a URL, an IP address, and a port number. I have tried using all of those in my code, but can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit:

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182900/php-websocket-on-bluehost) that apparently, you need shell access, which is only available with a VPS or dedicated server. I verified this with Bluehost chat support. And using SSH shell access, you can then run the socket.io server continuously in the background. Does this seem right? It seems like a lot of trouble for something that a lot of apps probably use...

Even when I run this off the localhost, I have to use node in the terminal to run the socket.io server.

And it looks like a dedicated server is required to be able to open ports.

Comment: The problem can be in your host. Maybe you didn't open ports correctly, didnt start server correctly etc. Check if your port is open.  And check if you can access to websocket with that port.

Comment: After doing a port scan, port 3306 that comes with Bluehost is not open, but neither is port 3000, which I was using successfully with localhost. I also tried running on localhost using port 3306 instead of 3000, and that worked. It just won't work either way running off my Bluehost server.

Comment: Most hosting companies block almost all ports by default. You need to open ports in your server management panel and/or your server. As explained here you can open any ports over 1024. https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/405